# Adding a value to a PHP associative array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm passing an array inside a GET(url) call like this:

```
 &item[][element]=value
```

Then I do my stuff in PHP:

```
$item = $_GET['item'];

    foreach ($item as $aValue) {
     foreach ($aValue as $key => $value) {

    echo '$key $value';
```

The problem I'm facing is that I need to have(echo) a third 'value':

```
echo '$key $value $thirdValue';
```

Do I have to change my the URL I'm passing or the foreach? And how do I do that? I Googled but I can't make heads nor tails out of it.

Comment: Where is this third value coming from?

Comment: From the URL Im passing

Comment: Where, though? Is it just `...&thirdValue=derp`?

Comment: Show the actual URL you are using to invoke your PHP script, with real parameters

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol That's what I cant figure out, I don't no where to place it in the URL. It needs to be in the foreach though, something like this `&item[][element, element3??]=value`

Comment: If it's just `&thirdValue=derp`, then you can just `echo $_GET['thirdValue']` inside your loop...

Comment: `$item=array_values($item); echo $item[2];`

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol No then it will stand at its own, I need it to be in the foreach

Comment: Arrays work on key, value. You don't add a third, you just add another key value pair. Also I'm dubious that you're really passing an array in a URL since you didn't mention serialization/deserialization or show it in the code...

Comment: So put the `echo` inside the `foreach`!

Comment: if you want to echo only one value then what is the use of foreach loop ?

Comment: @Youss: `item[element]=value&item[element2]=value2&item[element3]=value3`, maybe?

Comment: @Digital Chris I need to echo something like this `item1,item2,item3` And then repeat with different values, so that why Im using the foreach

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol If I just echo as a different item then my output will be: item1,item2 item1,item2 thirdItem While I need it to be: item1,item2,thirdItem item1,item2,thirdItem

Comment: Put it ***INSIDE*** the `foreach`! How much clearer do I need to make this?

Comment: @Youss check ans its that your requirement ?

Comment: OK, that's really basic array use. Set up the array properly on the calling page, serialize it,(or otherwise urlsafe and json encode it) and deserialize it on the resulting page. Why haven't you provided an example url with `?item=`?

Comment: @Digital Chris Of course Im serialize and doing all kinds of stuff but I dont see the point of sharing all of my code...

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol Its not going to work, it will only output one value over and over again

Answer (score 1):

```
$item = $_GET['item'];
$item_temp=array_values($item);
    foreach ($item as $aValue) {
     foreach ($aValue as $key => $value) {

    echo '$key $value'.$item_temp[2];
   }
  }
```

Comment: How would the URL look like then?

Comment: @Youss you have values which type of url you need ?

Comment: `&item1[][item2]=item3` Where do I put item4 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$item = $_GET['item'];
$r=array();
foreach($item as $rt){
    array_push($r,array(key($rt)=> $rt));
}

foreach($r as $rt){

foreach($rt as $rt2){
$k = key($rt2);
    echo $k.'__'.$rt2[$k] ;
    echo "<br>";
}

}

?>
```

it's Work .

Comment: What do I have to change about the URL Im sending?

Comment: nothing. just you should send url like this: `?item[][element]=value&item[][element2]=value2&item[][element3]=value3...`

Comment: Sorry It doesn't work...I already had the exact same output with the code in my question, it only outputs two variables. This is the output: `element3__value3` While I need it to output like so: `element3__value3__value4` So it should hold **3 items** not two...

Comment: i know how to do.but you can Give Var's And Use it ...` echo $k.'__'.$rt2[$k] ;
    echo "<br>";` you should custom it for you...

Comment: It's not about customizing, Its about holding values. Your code only holds two values each time, which is exactly the same as my code. Im right back where I was...